# During upgrade, database raised exception 9002, severity 17, state 1. Use the exception number to determine the cause

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I am trying to update the **SQL Server 2014** to **Service Pack 3** on my Windows Server Machine. After the updates from Windows update feature I am unable to start the SQL Server service and SQL Server Agent Service.

[image: services]

[image: error1]

I have checked the Error log for the same and it's showing below 2 messages.

> 1. The transaction log for database 'master' is full due to 'CHECKPOINT'.
> 2. During upgrade, database raised exception 9002, severity 17, state 1. Use the exception number to determine the cause.

Comment: Why are trying to install SSMS 2014? 18.8 came out quite recently. [Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) Though the errors you give are installed errors for SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu - There are several dependency with the sharepoint 2013. Due to the same I won't be able to jump to SSMS 2018 directly

Comment: Are you aware that Management Studio (a client application) and SQL Server and SQL Server Agent services are not related in a way that updating the Management Studio would cause a problem on those services? Also I don't think there's a service pack for SSMS, so it must be a service pack for SQL Server itself. How much free space do you have on the drive where the master database resides?

Comment: SSMS 18.8 is compatible with SQL Server 2008-2019. It has no relation to Share Point; SSMS is an IDE for SQL Server and nothing more.

Comment: ok my bad..... it's all about the SQL not related to IDE

Comment: @Ronaldo Actually SSMS 2014 was bundled with the SQL Server installer back then, so yes they are potentially related (e.g. someone could try to install SSMS with the SQL Server installer and choose the wrong components botching their SQL Server instance, assuming they were running the installer on the same machine the instance is installed to, which may be true in OPs case). In the context of OPs question though, we're unsure if he really meant SSMS 2014 or SQL Server 2014. (I'm assuming the latter since he mentioned service pack though.)

Comment: @J.D. sorry for the confusion.... it's all about the SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @J.D., I meant they're not related in a way that updating SSMS could break SQL Server as in SQL Server service has no dependency on SSMS, even though they're shipped together. But he updated the OP and SSMS has nothing to do with his problem anyway =)

Comment: @Ronaldo, Right, agreed on its own SSMS is unrelated. Coincidentally when OP misspoke he referred to the last version of SSMS that was shipped with the SQL Server installer, so before we knew what he actually meant all bets were off at that point lol (e.g. a botched install breaking SQL Server that was meant to only update SSMS). But yea as you said, we have more context now and SSMS isn't even relevant to this issue lol.

Comment: why downvoted??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 9002 :-

Thanks **@Ronaldo** and **@J.D.**

I have resolved the problem by using below actions.

**Perform below steps in case master file transaction log is full :-**

1. You have to setup another SQL instance running the exact same release and build.
2. Create database master2
3. stop the SQL Services and goto .mdf and .ldf file location "**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA**".
4. Remove the master2.mdf and master2_log.ldf files.
5. take our master.mdf and mastlog.ldf files which is having issue related to transaction log. rename both the file as below:

   a. master.mdf -> master2.mdf

   b. mastlog.ldf -> master2_log.ldf
6. start the SQL Services again and connect to the database from SSMS.
7. you can see the master2 database is showing state as recovery pending

**Common steps :-**

8. Take master2 database offline

[image: Take Offline]

9. Either remove or rename master2.ldf file from **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA"**
10. Execute below command which will rebuild the transaction log file again.

`ALTER DATABASE master2 REBUILD LOG ON (NAME= logicalname, FILENAME='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master2_log.ldf')`

11. Take master2 database Online
12. Execute below command

```
`ALTER DATABASE master2 SET MULTI_USER`
```

13. we will run the DBCC CHECKDB command below, in order to check the physical
    consistency of the database after rebuilding the SQL Transaction Log file

```
`DBCC CHECKDB (master2)`
```

14. after this replace the master2.mdf & master2_Log.ldf file to your original Sql server instance (rename the files back to original name) and try to connect now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method. Some observations: Step 1 is not needed, you can do step 2 using any instance of SQL Server 2014 or above you already have. Steps 12 and 13 are not related to the solution of the instance not starting, `WSS_Content` is a SharePoint database and not a SQL Server system database.

Comment: @Ronaldo - updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SQL Server are you running? Does [this StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101585/150011) help resolve any off the issues?

[**Exception 9002**](https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/error-9002-transaction-full/) basically means your **Transaction Log** is full, likely regarding the `master` database, as related to your first error.

With the SQL services offline, the quickest solution might be to make more space available in the drive that the **Transaction Log** for `master` lives on so it can grow the file enough, as needed, so you can start the service and then troubleshoot better, like taking a backup of `master` so it shrinks the **Transaction Log** file. The amount of space you'll need to free up is hard to determine (and dependent on what the growth factor is set to for the `master` database), but maybe an equal amount to its existing log size (so it can double if needed) is a good start.

After the additional details you posted in the comments (you should put them in your original question, by the way) I'm wondering if you possibly have a corrupt `master` database. In any case, this [StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164303/150011) might prove very useful to you. Particularly if you can do steps #3 or #4:

> 3. Restore master to another instance and copy its files
> 4. Rebuild the system databases

But start with #2 (trying to start the instance in **single user mode**) then follow the aforementioned answer in order.

Comment: I have already extended the disk space size but it's still showing the same error. Also as I am not able to connect to the database (Services are throwing an error) then how can I shrink the databases

Comment: @Mr.Roshan I didn't say anything about `shrinking`. How big is the `master` log file currently, how big is the drive it's on, and how much free space is left on that drive?

Comment: Yes.... whenever we took the backup that time shrinking process also takes place right.....but we are in the situation where we won't be able to connect to the database and right now there is almost 1TB+ space is available on the drive also the size of master.mdf(4 MB) and mastlog.ldf (2 MB)

Comment: @Mr.Roshan My answer suggests making free space on the drive first so you're able to eventually connect to the server, knowing you're currently unable to connect, as it states. It is very strange you have over 1 TB of free space where the log file is and the log file is only 2 MB big (but complaining it's full). Maybe the `master` database was configured to grow to a max size, which it now hit. I'll have to think how you can work around that and will update my answer when I can.

Comment: Sure @J.D. ................

Comment: @Mr.Roshan Please see my updated answer and best of luck!

Comment: My guess is that there was some confusion on how SQL Server works, and shrinking for the master database was performed. As an analogy: You have a full disk and you address this by making the disk smaller. So master now has an absurdly small size (4 MB data and 2 MB log) which is the root cause of the (current) problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring that problematic master on another instance to resize the log file:

1. Rename the original master database `.mdf` and `.ldf` files and make
   copies of them (we don't wanna make things worse);
2. Attach the copied files on a different SQL Server instance to check
   the state of that database:

   ```
   USE [master];
   CREATE DATABASE [master2] ON 
   ( FILENAME = N'C:\BackupSQL\master2.mdf' ),
   ( FILENAME = N'C:\BackupSQL\mastlog2.ldf' )
    FOR ATTACH;
   ```
3. Resize the log file:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE master2
   MODIFY FILE (NAME = mastlog, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, SIZE = 50MB);
   ```
4. detach the master2 database and paste the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files back
   to the original place (remember to keep the original `.mdf` and `.ldf`
   files with a different name, don't delete them as they might be
   needed in case this doesn't work) and rename the new ones as `master.mdf` and
   `mastlog.ldf`.
5. Try to start SQL Server service now.

Comment: I have tried to Create database by renaming the .mdf &.ldf files on another instance but getting same error while creating the database

Comment: @Mr.Roshan, try the option to create a new Log file: `CREATE DATABASE [master2] 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\BackupSQL\master2.mdf') 
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;` on another instance.

Comment: @Mr.Roshan were you able to use the above option for creating a new log file during the attach process or it caused some error too?

Comment: I am able to create it but by using little bit different approach

Comment: @Mr.Roshan please, share that approach with us. Did it solve the problem of the service not starting? If yes, you could write it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Sure @Ronaldo..! I will add it as an answer. do you have any idea why there is downvote for my question?

Comment: @Mr.Roshan it's hard to say for sure what was the reason of the downvote. Particularly, I'm not very fond of downvotes with no reasons given too, but my guess is that the question shows no research effort or is unclear (or at least it was at first when you asked about SSMS - and you still has a info about a Windows Server R2 and there's no such Windows version). If you rest your mouse over the downvote arrow, those are some of the guidelines for downvoting a question.